# What does 'open-work' mean here?

Tags: meaning

From *The invisible man*:

> His feet, save for socks of irregular open-work, were bare, his big toes were broad, and pricked like the ears of a watchful dog.

[This is the complete chapter](http://www.thecabinet.com/library/story.php?sub_id=horror_library&story_id=the_invisible_man&chapter_order=9).

The sentence means this guy was barefooted, but I'm not sure what *open* means, there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Openwork (or open-work) is any style of fabric that is made with holes included, such as crochet, lace doilies, or some forms of quilt.  It's also used for metal structures that have holes, but I believe this is less common.

It seems odd to hear it used for socks.  Socks are usually knitted, and I don't see any reason to knit holes into socks.  I guess it's a metaphor - these socks were so ragged that they seemed to have been made as openwork.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if the socks were of a rather loose weave.